# Constraint em uma primary key - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um problema para entender qual a intenção nesse código abaixo ao colocar uma *constraint* para criar uma chave primária de uma chave estrangeira.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    IdCustomer integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    NmCustomer varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CpfCnpj numeric NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AddressType(
    CdAddressType char(1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    AddressType varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CustomerAddress(
    IdCustomer integer,
    CdAddressType char(1),
    Street varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Lot integer NOT NULL,
    Reference varchar(255) NULL,
    ZipCode varchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_IdCustomer FOREIGN KEY (IdCustomer) REFERENCES Customer(IdCustomer),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CdAddressType FOREIGN KEY (CdAddressType) REFERENCES AddressType(CdAddressType),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerAddress PRIMARY KEY (IdCustomer, CdAddressType)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Criação da chave primária da tabela `CustomerAddress`:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerAddress PRIMARY KEY (IdCustomer, CdAddressType)
```

Criação de 2 chaves estrangeiras:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_IdCustomer FOREIGN KEY (IdCustomer) REFERENCES Customer(IdCustomer),
CONSTRAINT FK_CdAddressType FOREIGN KEY (CdAddressType) REFERENCES AddressType(CdAddressType),
```

Na coluna `IdCustomer` da tabela `CustomerAddress` só é possível adicionar valores que existam na coluna com o mesmo nome da tabela `Customer`.

Na coluna `CdAddressType` da tabela `CustomerAddress` só é possível adicionar valores que existam na coluna com o mesmo nome da tabela `AddressType`.